# What does it mean that SpiderMonkey is threadsafe?

Tags: javascript, c++, c++11, mozilla, spidermonkey

I can build SpiderMonkey as a library and use it as a Javascript engine in my C++ application.

In the documentation is been specified that SpiderMonkey is threadsafe, but what does it mean since Javascript/Ecmascript doesn't currently even have a threading model. What kind of calls or expressions are qualified as "safe" with this phrase about SpiderMonkey ? It's just about a piece of C++ code calling any JS functionality from any C++ thread to the Javascript virtual machine ?

Comment: JavaScript itself doesn't have threads, but a JS compiler/interpreter almost certainly does.  But all that's beside the point.

Comment: @cHao yes, but still, what are the nitty gritty details about that assertion ? As a C++ programmer ( C++11/C++14 ) how I should consider that phrase ?

Comment: With a bit of cynicism.  :P  If it turns out to be true, it means the library takes care of whatever synchronization is needed.  If your app only uses one thread, though, the synchronization won't mean much.

Comment: @cHao I'm going to use a task model or a multithreaded queue in my application, so it's going to be multithreaded for sure, that's why it makes a difference for me, for example LUA doesn't look like it's offering this option on thread safety, nor does V8 apparently, that's why I'm interested in SpiderMonkey, but I still need to understand what this "threadsafety" is about .

Comment: It means what thread safety means anywhere else -- that you don't have to be paranoid about multiple threads using the library at the same time.  The library will handle synchronization between calling threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread-safety of a library means that the library can be used in a multithreaded environment. **SpiderMonkey library can be integrated into a multithreaded C++ application.** That has nothing to do with JavaScript language model.

**However certain rules and restrictions apply**. Theses rules are confusing as they have been changing from one version of the library to another and the documentation wasn't and still isn't very clear about them. 
Documentation pages often display notes like: "Deprecated since..." or "DRAFT IN PROGRESS...", or "Not Found 404".

Starting in Gecko 12.0 or SpiderMonkey 24, the rules are:

- JSRuntime is single-threaded. You must only use it from one thread
- To call the library APIs from more that one thread at once, use multiple JSRuntimes
- In a JS_THREADSAFE build, many JSAPI functions must only be called
  from within a request (JS_THREADSAFE is now permanently on)
- Bracket API calls with JS_BeginRequest, JS_EndRequest functions or
  use JSAutoRequest class
- Garbage Collector suspends all other threads calling into SpiderMonkey. To keep wait time to a minimum, avoid long-running requests. Do not include blocking I/O or time-consuming calculations inside JS_BeginRequest, JS_EndRequest blocks.

You may consider building a **debug** version of SpiderMonkey to test your integration. Try using flags:

```
--enable-root-analysis --enable-debug --disable-optimize
```

Those add assertions in the library code to help catching thread (garbage collector, and memory) related problems earlier.

Comment: so I'm also assuming that internally it uses mutexes as a mechanism for synchronization, meaning that internally the execution of Spidermonkey is blocking a given thread until that operation is executed . Even if I run spidermonkey in a separate thread, when I call SM my application will be blocked by its mutex .

Comment: @user2485710 It doesn't matter what mechanism is used for synchronisation. You application won't be blocked by SM unless all threads are calling into SM. If they do they may potentially start competing for shared resources. If you have a single SM thread then other threads have nothing to compete for unless they are blocked waiting for a lengthy JavaScript to complete.

Answer (score 1):

It's threadsafe in regard to your C++ application. You can use the library from multiple threads inside your C++ code, without concern for locking data structures, etc.

In this context, it's irrelevant what the library does (in your case, execute JS code). What matters is that the library itself can be used in a multithreaded environment.

From Wikipedia:

> Implementation is guaranteed to be free of race conditions when
>   accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

[Read more about thread safety in Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)

Comment: thank you but your answer doesn't seems to be about SpiderMonkey, I know what threadsafe generally means, but what if Mozilla means that is threadsafe only in relation to the threads used inside the JS virtual machine ? are you sure you are talking about the specs of the SpiderMonkey engine ?

Comment: @user2485710: If they say it is threadsafe, then they had better mean *to code that's using it*.  If they mean anything else, they're incompetent.

Comment: @cHao from that prospective, both C++ and JS code can "use" spidermonkey, I also haven't found any example related to this thread safety. I mean it's a peculiar aspect of SpiderMonkey, something unique that many other VMs for other scripting languages do not offer, and it's not even documented in the details ?

Comment: @user2485710: Considering that JS doesn't *have* threads, it's not going to have a race condition with itself.  So obviously, it's the C++ code that cares about thread safety, and the C++ code that had better be able to trust in such a guarantee if it's given.